Understanding linear regression output for ordinal independent variable
I'm running a linear regression on JASP with an ordinal independent variable (education level with levels 1, 2, 3) and I am wondering what is meant when the coefficient table includes different numbers next to the education level variable ("education(2)" and "education(3)").
Would I interpret this as the effect of education level 2 and level 3 on the dependent variable? 

The numbers here indicate how much the conditional mean of the dependent variable increases/decreases as a result of being in Education 2, Education 3, etc., where the intercept is the conditional mean for Education 1 when not enrolled (Enrolled = 0). It is conditional because this mean changes based off the terms in your linear equation.
For example, being in the Education 1 group means you have a conditional mean number of correct scores that is around 5.118. This mean decreases by about -0.095 (resulting in a mean of 5.023) at Education 2 and increases from Education 1 by about 1.219 (resulting in a mean of 6.337 for Education 3). Being enrolled would increase the intercept's conditional mean by 1.600. Note that all of this would be the same if you fit the model with a nominal variable, as both get treated as categorical in JASP.
